# Toggle List and Grid View

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, gridview

I've made a simple toggle list/grid view using jQuery. My question is how can I make this code i.e. the jQuery more efficient (better coding)? Here is some dummy code based on the code I have in my project:

HTML:

```html
<div class="toggle-view">
  <span class="list l-active">List view</span>
  <span class="grid">Grid view</span>
</div>

<ul id="listing-view">
  <li>Listing Block</li>
  <li>Listing Block</li>
  <li>Listing Block</li>
  <li>Listing Block</li>
  <li>Listing Block</li>
  <li>Listing Block</li>
  <li>Listing Block</li>
  <li>Listing Block</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
.toggle-view span {
  color: #00804e;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-view .l-active {
  color: #c4c3c1;
  cursor: auto;
}

.list-view li {
  width: 100%
}

.grid-view li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

jQuery:

```js
$('.toggle-view span').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
    $('#listing-view').addClass('grid-view');
    $('.toggle-view span').addClass('l-active');
    $('.toggle-view span.list').removeClass('l-active');
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('list')) {
    $('#listing-view').removeClass('grid-view');
    $('.toggle-view span').addClass('l-active');
    $('.toggle-view span.grid').removeClass('l-active');
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by elegant?

Comment: See my OP intro, I've amended it.

Comment: It's fine the way it is.  I don't see what you could do, other than remove the duplicate line of code in each `if` statement, but you'd then need more code to handle that.  Alternatively, have 2 click event handlers, but again it's not needed.

Comment: OK thanks, I guess one thing I could do is make variables for repeated calls to the same html elements for example: .toggle-view span??

Comment: You *could* do, but I really don't think it would make much difference as you'd still need to do the 2nd find to get the list or grid class spans.

Answer (score 2):

See this...

```js
$('.toggle-view span').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
    $('#listing-view').addClass('grid-view');
    $('.toggle-view .list').removeClass('l-active');
  } else {
    $('#listing-view').removeClass('grid-view');
    $('.toggle-view .grid').removeClass('l-active');
  }
  $(this).addClass('l-active');
});
```

Greetings.